# React npm error “npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE” when I do npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm working on a React application. When I'm using the command `npm start`, it gives an error. I tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and then doing `npm install`. I also tried doing `npm cache clean --force`. The last thing I did was `npm audit fix`. I still have the same issue. Here is my error:

```
> majestic-bay@0.1.0 start /home/serg/webdev/majestic-bay
> react-scripts start

/home/serg/webdev/majestic-bay/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/p-limit/index.js:30
                } catch {}
                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:136:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:197:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:11:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! majestic-bay@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the majestic-bay@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/serg/.npm/_logs/2020-11-06T06_52_29_568Z-debug.log
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "majestic-bay",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is the content of the error file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/home/serg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/serg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v9.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle majestic-bay@0.1.0~prestart: majestic-bay@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle majestic-bay@0.1.0~start: majestic-bay@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle majestic-bay@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle majestic-bay@0.1.0~start: PATH: /home/serg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/serg/webdev/majestic-bay/node_modules/.bin:/home/serg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin:/home/serg/.local/bin:/home/serg/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/cxoffice/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/opt/cxoffice/bin:/home/serg/.yarn/bin:/home/serg/.yarn/bin
9 verbose lifecycle majestic-bay@0.1.0~start: CWD: /home/serg/webdev/majestic-bay
10 silly lifecycle majestic-bay@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle majestic-bay@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle majestic-bay@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: majestic-bay@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/serg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:180:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/serg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:936:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5)
14 verbose pkgid majestic-bay@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/serg/webdev/majestic-bay
16 verbose Linux 5.8.18-1-MANJARO
17 verbose argv "/home/serg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/node" "/home/serg/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.2/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v9.11.2
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error majestic-bay@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the majestic-bay@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Delete the node module and run npm install again

Comment: @tadman yes, but I don't have it in package.json file. How do I update it then?

Comment: @SohailAshraf I tried it many times. It's not the issue for sure.

Comment: `terser-webpack-plugin` seems to have a bad dependency, so remove it and re-add it to get the latest version, or use an [update checking package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates). If this is a bad version you may need to force downgrade to a specific working version, plus file a bug report if you can.

Comment: @tadman ok but how do I remove it if I don't have it in the package.json?

Comment: Is there an easy way to reproduce this problem so we can help test? Is there some simple steps with `react-cli`?

Comment: @tadman I believe it's a specific problem to my computer. I think so because I'm using creat-react-app and I basically just created my application a couple days ago and haven't really put any code there.

Comment: Try the usual stuff: Check your Node version. Check for package updates. Check if an older version of this code still works. Hopefully you're using version control so checking that can be easy, e.g. `git bisect`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, it was the node version. I had v9.11.2, so when I installed version v12.19.0, it fixed it.

Comment: If you _have_ to get this running under an older version of node.js (in my case v8.x), downgrading `react-scripts` to 3.4.2 (`terser-webpack-plugin` is a dependency) enabled me to dev & build without errors.